# How to autowire different services depending on environment in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

I have a service with an interface that is Autowired by spring. I now wish to autowire an other service if the production environment is development. How would I go about doing this?.

The inteface looks like this.

```
public interface ClientServiceInterface {

  public User getUser(String ID);

  public List<User> getUsersByDepartment(String department) 

  public void initialize();

}
```

The interface is implemented by ClientMockServiceImpl and ClientServiceImpl. I Wish to use the mock service in development. Both classes use the @Service annotation. I wish that my autowiring of the service would change depending on prod env.

Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: Check [Spring Profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/) blogpost shows how profiling works in Spring MVC. You can register different profiles by putting appropriate `@Profile` annotations before bean registration classes:

```
@Bean
@Profile("prod")
public UserService userService() {
        return new UserService();
}

@Bean
@Profile("dev")
public UserService devUserService() {
        return new UserService();
}
```